# Chat with websocket working in local but unable to connect on server

Tags: php, websocket

I made a chat for a site hosted with o2switch, the chat work perfectly in local, but when hosted, impossible to connect it.

I tried to write the address by many possibility, launch the webserver on differents ports.

Here the way to launch server in php:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())),
            8083


         );
    $server->run();

}
```

Here the connection in JS:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.namesite.com:8083');
```

**Error message :**

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://www.namesite.com:8083

Comment: 1. Ensure that web server is listening on 0.0.0.0:8083 (on Linux check it with 'netstat -nl | grep 8083), it should have line 0.0.0.0:8083 in LISTENiNG state
2. Check that firewall on server is configured correctly. Check it with 'telnet your.server.up 8083', it should connect

Comment: Sadly netstat and telnet not work on this server :
`bash: netstat: command not found`
`bash: telnet: command not found`

a `uname -a` give me :
`Linux truite.o2switch.net 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 22 10:39:25 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I added after 8083 on the start: ,'0.0.0.0' for force it to use this.

Comment: instead of 'netsstat' try 'ss': ss -t -l -n
instead of 'telnet' try 'nc': nc x.x.x.x 8083

Comment: I think there are nothing working in this server:
`bash: ss: command not found` and `bash: nc: command not found`